# Transferring files between linux and windows using sftp

Tags: ssh, windows, sftp

I am trying to sftp from my linux machine to a Windows host but I get connection refused.

```
[root@linux-host ~]# sftp my.user@windows-host
ssh: connect to host windows-host port 22: Connection refused.
```

However, if I try vice versa i.e. connecting to the linux host from the Windows host using psftp it works just fine:

```
PS C:\Users\my.user> psftp my.user@linux-host
Using username "my.user".
..
psftp> get /tmp/somefile somefile
remote:/tmp/somefile => local:somefile
```

Do `sftp` and `psftp` work on different ports? And if windows host can send file using `pfstp` doesn't that imply that it is also ready to receive through SFTP protocol?

My eventual aim is to be able to transfer files between Windows and linux host. Using *SCP/PSCP* isn't an options.

Comment: "And if windows host can send file using pfstp doesn't that imply that it is also ready to receive through SFTP protocol?" – Well, you have received `somefile` by using `get`, haven't you? From the context I understand you rather want your Windows to be a server. Still Windows as a client is ready to receive as well as to send.

Answer (score 1):

> And if windows host can send file using pfstp doesnt it imply that it is also ready to receive through SFTP protocol?

No.

Windows can connect to your Linux PC for sftp purposes, because your Linux runs an SSH server (which contains the sftp server).

Linux *cannot* connect to your Windows PC for sftp purposes, because your Windows does **not** run such a service.

Solution:

1. Either install an SSH server on your windows machine, or
2. Use Windows file sharing and `smbclient` (or mount the share, or access it elsewise) from Linux.

Comment: I can use scp/pscp to achieve the same, so scp doesn’t require any specific setup but sftp does?

Comment: The point is that the connection went the other direction.